# Python: writing and reading a dictionary on a file

Tags: python, file-io, dictionary

i'm trying to write a dictionary to a .txt file, and then read it from that same file again.

This is what i've got so far:

```
book = {'key1':'1','key2':'2'}

pfile = open("testfile.txt", "w+")
pfile.write("%s" % book)
pfile.close()

k1 = book['key1']
k2 = book['key2']

print(k1)
print(k2)

rfile = open("testfile.txt", "r")
rbook = rfile.read()

k1 = rbook['key1']
k2 = rbook['key2']

print(k1)
print(k2)
```

But when i try to run the .py it will return:

```
1
2
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "sotest.py", line 16, in <module>
    k1b = rbook['key1']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

I'm on a Mac by the way.

As i said, i want it to write the dictionary to the file, and then read the dictionary from that same file and print it again.

Could someone tell me what i'm doing wrong? Maybe give me an example of how i could make this code work?

Comment: You're not using [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html).

Comment: Or even [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).

Comment: Ow, ok, i indeed read something about those two, could you give me an example on how to use one of these in my code? @abc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read the dictionary from file the result is `string` and you cant tread with as a dictionary ! you can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert it to dictionary :

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("{'key1':'1','key2':'2'}")
{'key2': '2', 'key1': '1'}
```

but as a more efficient way you can use [`shelf`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module :

> A “shelf” is a persistent, dictionary-like object. The difference with “dbm” databases is that the values (not the keys!) in a shelf can be essentially arbitrary Python objects — anything that the pickle module can handle. This includes most class instances, recursive data types, and objects containing lots of shared sub-objects. The keys are ordinary strings.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a closer look at shelves! @Kasra

Answer (score 0):

You could use [the pickle library](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html) so you write (e.g.):

```
import pickle
pfile = open('filename.txt','wb')#binary mode for using pickle
pickle.dump(mydict, pfile)
pfile.close()
```

Or even if you want to do it more 'pythonic':

```
import pickle
with open('filename.txt','wb') as pfile:
    pickle.dump(mydict,pfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pickle` can have a possible security issue, whereby Python code can be ran upon loading the pickle. If a malicious user has replaced your pickle file with some malicious code then you're in trouble.

I would suggest using Javascript Object Notation, or JSON, for writing your dictionary to a file. Python has a builtin [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module which can provide loading and dumping data. The code below is a toy example which does this with a dictionary.

```
import json

d = {'a':1, 'b':[0,1,2,3]}

# j is now a string containing the data from d in the json format.
j = json.dumps(d)

with open('my_data.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(j)
```

You will now have a file `my_data.json` which contains your data. If you wish to re-read this in later you can use the below code:

```
with open('my_data.json', 'r') as f:
    new_d = json.loads(f.read())
```

After which, `d` and `new_d` will contain the same information.

```
print(d)
print(new_d)
# {'a': 1, 'b': [0, 1, 2, 3]}
# {'a': 1, 'b': [0, 1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: Ok, i'll have a look at JSON as well. Thanks!